# Rasterizing Shapefiles onto TIFF loses style

Tags: qgis, contour, rasterization

I have two contour shapefiles, one for 2ft and one for 10ft contours.  I want to put these on a TIFF file I have of the aerial.  I achieved this by going to Raster > Conversion > Rasterize and using the shapefile as input and the TIFF as the output and when this happens I get contours of a red and turquoise color.  I want the contours to be the same color all throughout the TIFF I load them on and also I want to be able to choose the color and style that I use.

I have tried changing styles of the contours and re-saving and also changing the Band type of my raster since it is a multi-band and I figured this was the source of my problem.  However, whenever I try this the TIFF file becomes different colors and unusable.  Attached is a picture with two arrows pointing to the two different colors the contours come in when I go through the Rasterize tool.

[image]

Comment: Maybe `gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0`  to make it all red?

Comment: @Kazuhito  Well that was easy, it worked.  Thank you very much.  Would you like to post the solution or should I?

Comment: Sorry I had commented without testing it myself. Glad it worked anyway :)

Comment: Thanks! Will you please post the outcome as answer? Would like to see it.

Comment: @Kazuhito I will now.  Also any clue on how to change the styling of these lines?  Is there a different variable I can use in the line of code?  I need to make the one contour for 2ft dashed and then the contour for 10ft  .5x dashed

Comment: That's interesting...but i have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Rasterize tool panel at the bottom press the pencil to edit the code after you select your input and output files. Copy and paste `gdal_rasterize -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -burn 255 -burn 0 -burn 0` in the start of the code replacing the first 'gdal_rasterize'.  This will make all the contours a red color.  To change the color figure out the RGB numbers and replace respectively with the 255,0, & 0.

The image attached is what the contours ended up looking like after making the one contour color '255,0,0' and the other as '46,30,128'.
[image]