# Adding graticule overlay to satellite image

Tags: python, gdal, satellite, sentinel-1

I'm developing a python script to turn Sentinel-1 satellite images in .SAFE-format into easy-to-read jpeg images. The calibration and projection works fine using gdal, but I am having trouble with the last part.

I want the generated image to have a graticule overlay, making it possible to reference geographical spots on the image. I feel that such a normal problem would have a built-in function or some library to solve, but I can't seem to find any. Does anyone have any ideas or tips on this matter?

Since the tif-file have the coordinates of each pixel it would be possible to make a transparent copy of the image, drawing the lat/long lines "by hand" using PIL and then placing this image on top of the other, but this seems like an awful lot of work.

I'm fairly new with gdal.

---

[image: Sentinel-1 test image from Barents Sea]

Using mkgraticule.py i've managed to make the grid lines I wanted. However, they won't help that much if they're not numbered (lat/long for each line). From what I can see mkgraticule don't have this option so I suppose I'll have to find another way.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange. I don't have any first-hand experience using this, but have you checked out Frank Warmerdam's mkgraticule.py? (see https://github.com/postmates/gdal/blob/master/scripts/mkgraticule.py). I believe it makes a shapefile you could then combine with your images using other gdal functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be exactly what I need, I will look into it right away.

Comment: Prepare the graticule as vectors and burn it into image with gdal_rasterize. Rather similar task in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247052/rasterizing-shapefiles-onto-tiff-loses-style/247061#247061

Comment: Burning the shp file into the image seems easy enough since the functions are pretty well documented, but I can't seem to find any documentation for the mkgraticule.py-script. `python mkgraticule.py --help` just shows the syntax. When I run `python mkgraticule.py outfile.tif` it returns an error saying outfile.tif does not exist. And if I use a existing tif-file it overwrites it. Thanks again for the response.

Comment: The script creates a new shapefile as output with the name you give it on the commandline. So, if all goes well, it would create outfile.shx, outfile.shp, outfile.prj and outfile.dbf.

Comment: Yea, I got confused since the script throws an error, but it's just to ignore it. Everything works fine and the files are created.

Comment: Some alternative methods could be to show your data with a simple application that adds the graticule http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/graticule.html or to make some WMS server that supports graticule layer for creating the JPEG output, for example http://mapserver.org/mapfile/grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to GIS StackExchange. I don't have any first-hand experience using this, but have you checked out Frank Warmerdam's mkgraticule.py? (see github.com/postmates/gdal/blob/master/scripts/mkgraticule.py‌​). I believe it makes a shapefile you could then combine with your images using other gdal functions.

Found another goodie you might want to take a look at here (https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2015-June/041999.html) links to 
https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2015-June/041999.html

Comment: Thanks again, I'm working with it now, i'll comment later on how it goes :)